# Can games be made with Win32 for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, win32

Based on the news today of Microsoft allowing Win32 games on the Windows store, what does it mean that Win32 can be used for games now?  Couldn't Windows 10 already play Win32 games?  or is this solely for distribution over the Window Store 
that is important?

Couldn't Windows 10 already play Win32 games?  What were developers using if it wasn't Win32 on Windows 10 (UWP?)

Quoted in many articles, but here is the original,

https://news.xbox.com/en-us/2019/05/30/microsoft-approach-to-pc-gaming/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always make games for Windows 10 using the Win32 API, yes.

What you could *not* do was distribute those games on the Microsoft Store. Microsoft Store products had to be made with UWP.

The linked announcement is saying (among the Game Pass things) that Microsoft will be enabling a mechanism by which you can distribute Win32 games via the Microsoft Store.